# Index for queries with $ne and $or with arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

Say I have a MongoDB collection with documents like this:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("the_object_id"),
  "type": "BLOG_POST",
  "state": "IN_PROGRESS",
  "createDate":ISODate("2017-02-15T01:01:01.000Z"),
  "users": {
      "posted": ["user1", "user2", "user3"],
      "favorited": ["user1", "user4", "user5", "user6"],
      "other_fields": "other data",
   },
   "many_more_fields": "a bunch of other data"
}
```

I have a query like this:

```
db.collection.find({"$and":[
    {"type": "BLOG_POST"},
    {"$or": [ {"users.posted":"userX"}, {"users.favorited":"userX"} ] },
    {"state": {"$ne":"COMPLETED"}}
]}).sort({"createDate":1})
```

The collection currently only has indexes on the _id field and some fields not included in this query or example.

As far as the cardinality goes, documents with:
type=BLOG_POST is approximately 75% of the collection, state $ne "COMPLETED" is approximately 50% of the collection, and users are in the users.posted or users.favorited at most 2% of the collection.

What would the best index or set of indexes be for this use case?

It is my understanding that we cannot index both users.posted and users.favorited in the same index because they are both arrays. In the future we may be able to make a new array of users.userswhocare which is a set of both of the fields, but assume we can't make that change in the short term.

I also thought that the $ne on state means that an index on state will generally not be used. Is the query planner able to the state field at the end of an index to handle the $ne condition?

I had the idea of an index {"type":1, "createDate":1, "state":1}, so that the query would hit on the type, use the createDate for the sort, and handle the $ne with last bit of the index.  It would still have to pick up 35%-40% of the documents to test for the users.  Not good, but an improvement over the current collection scan.

Alternatively I could create two indexes, one like {"users.posted":1, "type":1, "createDate":1, "state":1} and {"users.favorited":1, "type":1, "createDate":1, "state":1}.
Will the query planner use the intersection of these two indexes to more quickly find the documents of interest?

We are currently using MongoDB 3.2.5.  If there are differences in the answer between MongoDB 3.2 and 3.4, I would love to know them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some analysis, I found that adding multiple queries with `users.posted` and `users.favorited` as the first item in the respective indexes both performed better and was chosen by the MongoDB query planner.

I created indexes like:

```
db.collection.createIndex({"users.posted":1, "type":1, "createDate":1, "state":1})
db.collection.createIndex({"users.favorited":1, "type":1, "createDate":1, "state":1})
```

Due to the cardinality of users.posted and users.favorited being high (either one will encompass no more than 2% of the collection, most of the time less than 0.5%), the MongoDB query planner used both with index intersection.

I tested this against an index like:

```
db.collection.createIndex({"type":1, "createDate":1, "state":1}).
```

Reviewing the explain plans of against both queries using both `explain()` and `explain("executionStats")`, the query planner used index scans for the {"$or": [ {"users.posted":"userX"}, {"users.favorited":"userX"} ] } part of the query as the first stage. This led to the fewest totalKeysExamined and totalDocsExamined.